# Unable to Connect to Local SQL Server with Windows Authentication using SSMS

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, ssms, windows-authentication

I'm trying to login to my local SQL Server 2005 installed on Windows7 using SSMS using Windows authentication.

I tried using various server names like `.`, `localhost`, `.\SQL`, `ANANTH-PC` etc.

I get this error when I try `.` or `localhost`

[image]

And I get this error when I try `.\SQL`

.[image]

I had gone for default instance and Windows authentication when I installed SQL Server.

I've checked the service in the SQL Server Configuration manager and find that `MSSQLSERVER` is running.

How can I find the server name that I should enter to login to SQL Server? Any help ?

Error is loged as

```
2012-01-26 15:07:16.02 Logon       Login failed for user 'Ananth-PC\Ananth'. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
2012-01-26 15:08:51.06 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 11.
```

Comment: The first error message indicates that your `.` is correct - just your user doesn't have any permission to log on..... I would try to log on to `.` with the `sa` account and the password you gave that account when installing.... the default instance of SQL Server can be accessed via `.` (or `(local)`) - if you installed SQL Server **Express**, the default instance name would be `.\SQLEXPRESS` (or again: `(local)\SQLEXPRESS`)

Comment: Thanks marc.  But I havnt given any password during SQLServer installation as I'd gone for Windows Authentication (not Mixed). So how do I go ahead from here ?

Comment: @marc_s - I tried .\SQLEXPRESS as well. Its not working as I dont have SQLEXPRESS

Comment: Under which user account did you do the installation?? Your own user, or did you run as `Administrator`?? That user account should automatically be granted access to the SQL Server instance, I believe

Comment: @marc_s . Thanks . But there is just a single user ("Ananth") in my machine.  But the error message that I get is "Login failed for Ananth-PC\Ananth.

Comment: @marc_s. Did you mean to try with SQLServerAuthentication with username as "Ananth" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should help you find reason. 
Click: "Show technical details" and look at State number.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/02/21/536201.aspx

Comment: Thanks. As per the link, the error is logged as Severity 11. Error Discription is "Valid login but server access failure".

Comment: Hmm. I think about login as admin: ADMIN:INSTANCE. More information here:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178068.aspx  Or just try to restart service:)

Comment: Thanks devarc. The answer guided me to the solution. I ran SSMS as admin and it worked fine.

Answer (score 10):

Ran SSMS as Administrator and issue was fixed.. Accepting the previous answer as it guided me to this solution

Answer (score 1):

For **SQL Server 2019 Express** on **SSMS**, **the default format of MSSQL Server Name** is:

```
<Your PC Name>/SQLEXPRESS
```

This is in my case below:

```
DESKTOP-HN1U0ME/SQLEXPRESS
```

[image]

For **SQL Server 2019 Developer** on **SSMS**, **the default format of MSSQL Server Name** is:

```
<Your PC Name>
```

This is in my case below:

```
DESKTOP-HN1U0ME
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this! My problem was I was used to using <Your PC Name>/SQLEXPRESS and when I installed the developer version I was trying to use <Your PC Name>/MSSQLSERVER when I needed to just use <Your PC Name>

Answer (score 0):

Please enable the administrator Account throngh this command
`secpol.msc` and enable admin and log the PC and Login the Administrator account and run SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 0):

Give server name as "**(LocalDb)\v11.0**" by selecting windows authentication. Please see the image.[image]

It worked for me with SQLServer 2014.

Comment: Even I also was not convinced when I got this solution from some source. But it worked for me wioith MS SQL 2014 . For that you need have installed SQL Server not only server management studio.