# SQL Server Mgmt Studio Change Back to Windows Auth

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

1st time user with SQL Server and after I logged in to 2012 Management Studio using Windows Authentication it worked well as expected.  While open, I attempted to change to SQL Sever Auth within the properties.  Now I want to go back to Windows Auth, but I cannot Connect to Server with Management Studio.

I don't want to have to go through the painful process of uninstalling everything and reinstalling, but is that my only option?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly understood your question, But I believe first you logged in into SSMS using Windows Authentication and when it was open you changed it to SQL Server Authentication and now you want to connect again to Windows, if this is the case then just click on highlighted area and in Authentication click Windows Authentication as provided in screenshot below.
PLEASE CORRECT ME IF MY UNDERSTANDING IS WRONG!!

[image]

If only connecting is not your problem then go through following links , it may be useful

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188670.aspx
http://blogs.adobe.com/LiveCycleHelp/2013/08/sql-server-in-windows-authentication-mode.html

Comment: @P Kernal - you are exactly right, but now my Windows Auth doesn't work anymore and wondering how I can change that back.

Comment: @jKraut can you mention the error message, it would be nice if you can provide screenshot for same.

Comment: @P Kernal - screenshots added in post

Comment: @jKraut try running SSMS as admin. I tried to replicate same issue in my PC and I closed SSMS first and then restarted it using **Run as Administrator** Option. Worked fine for me. Also go through link below if still issue exists.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016572/unable-to-connect-to-local-sql-server-with-windows-authentication-using-ssms